# Issues with functions in C and pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers, double

having trouble with this program I wrote.  In the updateCost(miles) and other other update___() I am getting the error that there are too few arguments in function call. I am also getting Error 5 error C2371: 'updateCurrentMileage' : redefinition; different basic types as well as the same error in void update cost. I am new to passing functions so I am quite a bit of a novice. I am also wondering if my arrays are doing what they're supposed to be doing, I can not tell as I can not the run the program. Any help as to why it is doing this and how I can fix it would be great, as I am trying to become a better programmer. Cheers.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


double arr[500];
double arr2[500];
double arr3[500];
double cost= 0.0;
double totalCost= 0.0;
double overallMiles = 0.0;
double overallMpg = 0.0;
double overallPricePerGallon = 0.0;

int choice;
int quit= 0;

int menuChoice () {

int choice;

    printf("     T a k e      a        D r i v e          \n");
    printf("1.Enter miles driven\n");
    printf("2.How much is price per gallon of gas?\n");
    printf("3.How many miles do you get per gallon?\n");
    printf("4.Total cost for trip\n");
    printf("5.How many miles have you drove in total?\n");
    printf("6.How much money have you spent total on gas?\n");
    printf("7.Quit\n");


    printf("Enter your choice:   ");
    scanf("%i", &choice);

    return choice;

}




double getMilesDriven() {

double miles;

        printf("Enter miles driven:\n");
        scanf("%lf", &miles);
        updateCurrentMileage(miles);
        updateCost(miles);

        return miles;

}




void updateCurrentMileage(double totalMiles) {


    overallMiles+=totalMiles;


}



double totalMiles () {



    return overallMiles;

}



double pricePerGallonOfGas() {


double price;

    printf("Enter price per gallon:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &price);
    updateCost(price);
    return price;

}




double myCarMpg() {

double myMpg;

    printf("How many miles per gallon do you get on your car?:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &myMpg);
    updateCost(myMpg);
    return myMpg;

}



void updateCost (double newMiles, double newPrice, double newMpg) {

    overallMiles = newMiles;
    overallMpg = newMpg;
    overallPricePerGallon = newPrice;



}




double costForTrip() {

    cost = (overallMiles / overallMpg) * overallPricePerGallon;

    return cost;

}




double  totalSpentonGas() {

    totalCost+= cost;

    return totalCost;

}




double main () {

{

while(quit!=1) //begin menu loop
{
    int menu;

    menu = menuChoice();

    //begin switch
    switch(menu)
    {
        case 1:
            {
            double result = getMilesDriven();
            arr[500]= result;


            break;
            }

        case 2:
            {
            double result= pricePerGallonOfGas(); 
            arr2[500]= result;
            break;
            }
        case 3:
            {
            double result= myCarMpg();
            arr3[500]= result;
            break;
            }
        case 4:
            if (overallMiles= 0)
            printf("Please enter miles driven, mpg and cost per gallon first!\n");
            else
             printf("Cost of trip is %lf\n", costForTrip());
            break;
        case 5:
            if (overallMiles= 0)
            printf("You haven't even drove any miles!\n");
            else
            printf("Current total mileage is %lf\n", totalMiles());
            break;
        case 6:
         if (cost = 0)
            printf("You haven't spent any money on gas!\n");
         else
            printf("Total spent on gas is %lf\n", totalSpentonGas());
            break;
        case 7:
            quit = 1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Please enter 1 through 6\n");
            break;
    } 
    } 
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You are calling `void updateCost (double newMiles, double newPrice, double newMpg)` several times with only one (different) argument. You must provide all three. And, you must either implement the function before any of the calls, or provide the **function prototype** `void updateCost (double newMiles, double newPrice, double newMpg);`so the compiler knows how it should be called.

Comment: Noone complained about the `double main()` yet?

Comment: That is no valid C program: `double main ()`. The signature is at least `int main(void)` for a hosted environment.

Comment: Even more surprising, is the requirement to enter **mpg** and not have the program calculate it. There *is* one divide in the program: watch out for **divide by 0**

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I didn't even realize I had double main (). Totally unintentional.

Answer (score 0):

In your getMilesDriven() method, you're calling `updateCost(miles);`, however you've defined that method as requiring three parameters:`void updateCost (double newMiles, double newPrice, double newMpg)`

Answer (score 0):

You are using functions before you have declared and defined them:

- `double getMilesDriven()`
- `double pricePerGallonOfGas()`
- etc.

are being used in your other functions before they have been declared/defined. Try rearranging your function declarations after you have declared their use. For example:

```
void updateCurrentMileage(double totalMiles) {
    overallMiles += totalMiles;
}

void updateCost(double newMiles, double newPrice, double newMpg) {

    overallMiles = newMiles;
    overallMpg = newMpg;
    overallPricePerGallon = newPrice;
}

double totalMiles() {
    return overallMiles;
}

double myCarMpg() {

    double myMpg;

    printf("How many miles per gallon do you get on your car?:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &myMpg);
    updateCost(myMpg);
    return myMpg;

}

double costForTrip() {

    cost = (overallMiles / overallMpg) * overallPricePerGallon;

    return cost;

}

double  totalSpentonGas() {
    totalCost += cost;
    return totalCost;
}

double pricePerGallonOfGas() {

    double price;

    printf("Enter price per gallon:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &price);
    updateCost(price);
    return price;
}

double getMilesDriven() {

    double miles;

    printf("Enter miles driven:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &miles);
    updateCurrentMileage(miles);
    updateCost(miles);

    return miles;
}
```

Also, you don't have to initialize your global variables - they will be initialized at compile time.

EDIT: and as others have noted `double main()` should be `int main()` to follow proper c programs as main should return an int (in simplest terms).

Answer (score 0):

your program don't have the numbers of lines, but, the problem is:
**if (overallMiles= 0)**, the correct is **if (overallMiles==0)** 
// 
and the function updateCost, you have 3 parameters
**updateCost (double newMiles, double newPrice, double newMpg)**

but you call it passing one parameter,  **updateCost(miles);**

and here, you are using the last position of array, not is a good idea.
**arr2[500]= result;**
If you aren't needs for others positions, can user a double var.